# Polymorphism when calling a static method from a static method in python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, static-methods

I am currently working on a problem where many classes will be based on a base class. I want these classes to inherit a static function from the base class which in turn calls a static function. This second static function will, however, be defined for each class.

A simple example would be:

```py
class foo():
   @staticmethod
   def fn1(x):
      return x

   @staticmethod
   def fn2(x, y):
      return foo.fn1(x + y)

class bar(foo):
   @staticmethod
   def fn1(x):
      return 2*x
```

With the above code `bar.fn2(1, 2)` returns `foo.fn1(1 + 2)` and I would instead like it to return `bar.fn1(1 + 2)`.

Is this possible to do with static methods in python without defining fn2 for each class?

Grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `fn2` a classmethod instead so that it has access to the class used to call the method:

```
@classmethod
def fn2(cls, x, y):
   return cls.fn1(x + y)
```